# Need help reading online txt data into r

Tags: r

Having difficulty reading http://kenpom.com/cbbga16.txt into R as a data frame, have tried

```
 read.table("http://kenpom.com/cbbga16.txt", header=FALSE, sep="\t" , fill=T)
```

but not able to get the columns correctly delimited. Please help!

Comment: The data has extra columns in some places, which will cause problems. You can get it in with `read.fwf`, though you'll have to set the widths (and probably clean up a bit afterwards).

Answer (score 1):

As [alistaire](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4497050/alistaire) mentioned above, you can use `read.fwf` with the following widths:

```
data <- read.fwf('http://kenpom.com/cbbga16.txt', widths=c(11,24,3,23,4,4,21))
```

Those widths are subjective to this data only, however. This would be easier to deal with if there were a delimiter of some sort. I'm guessing it got lost in translation to a text file.

Answer (score 1):

The `readr::read_table` function almost works for this out of the box. It parses each column and separates variables based on completely empty columns. Unfortunately it gets thrown off by the unequal row lengths.

```
> fileURL <- "http://kenpom.com/cbbga16.txt"
> 
> library(readr)
> library(stringr)
> library(tibble)
> 
> glimpse(read_table(fileURL, col_names = FALSE))
Observations: 3,244
Variables: 7
$ X1 <chr> "11/13/2015", "11/13/2015", "11/13/2015", "11/13/2015", "...
$ X2 <chr> "Washington", "Johnson FL", "Montana St.", "Monmouth", "K...
$ X3 <chr> "77", "71", "76", "84", "62", "58", "73", "60", "52", "72...
$ X4 <chr> "Texas", "Florida A&M", "Hawaii", "UCLA", "Columbia", "Se...
$ X5 <int> 71, 103, 87, 81, 107, 56, 89, 71, 80, 78, 82, 90, 41, 86,...
$ X6 <chr> "N", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1...
$ X7 <chr> "Shanghai, China", "3/2015 Pittsburgh Bradford     49 Buf...
>
```

Fortunately it is not too difficult to pad the rows to equal length:

```
> tmp <- read_lines(fileURL)
> tmp <- str_pad(tmp, width = max(str_length(tmp)), side = "right")
```

After that `read_table` is able to correctly determine the column boundaries:

```
> glimpse(read_table(str_c(tmp, collapse = "\n"), col_names = FALSE))
Observations: 5,952
Variables: 7
$ X1 <chr> "11/13/2015", "11/13/2015", "11/13/2015", "11/13/2015", "...
$ X2 <chr> "Washington", "Johnson FL", "Pittsburgh Bradford", "Monta...
$ X3 <chr> "77", "71", "49", "76", "65", "84", "56", "62", "50", "58...
$ X4 <chr> "Texas", "Florida A&M", "Buffalo", "Hawaii", "California"...
$ X5 <int> 71, 103, 109, 87, 97, 81, 80, 107, 70, 56, 74, 89, 63, 71...
$ X6 <chr> "N", "", "", "", "", "1", "", "", "", "", "", "", "2", ""...
$ X7 <chr> "Shanghai, China", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""...
>
```